# i need to let a user to add a role from a frontend form

Tags: users, user-roles

i need to let a registered user who already has role or 2 roles the ability to add himself a role via frontend form.
i tried to look for it and didn't find anything related that can help me.
any ideas?
thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think each user can only have one role.
However this is how its possible to change role, if for some reason that I dont know the user can have more than one role, remove the remove role line. you can check the available roles [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/).

```php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
// Remove role
$current_user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
// Add role
$current_user->add_role( 'editor' );
```

Comment: How did this answer the question about a front-end form?

Comment: this is the wordpress php code to do it, now just need html

Comment: actually in the end it helped me.. i wasn't looking at it from the right angle.